# Want to remove lines from file with awk that contain duplicated pattern

Tags: awk, duplicates

for example each line of a file contains something like this:

```
WordA WordB WordC:WordD WordE WordF
WordA WordB WordC:WordD WordE WordF
WordA WordB WordC:WordD WordE WordF
```

so i care only about WordC:WordD pattern, and in case of duplicates, i want to somehow retain only unique ones and discard repeated/duplicated ones.

for example, if i initially have lines like this:

```
cat dog bear:tiger mouse elephant
cat dog bear:lion wolf frog
cat mouse bear:tiger frog wolf
```

i want to get this result:

```
cat dog bear:tiger mouse elephant
cat dog bear:lion wolf frog
```

because, 3rd line's WordC:WordD pattern is duplicated.

So I have tried this but it prints all lines, even with duplicates:

```
awk '$0 ~ /.*[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+.*/ {if (!seen[$0]) {print; seen[$0] = 1}}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to add the regex match to `seen`:

*(updated to shorter notations after feedback from @[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) in the comments)*

```
awk 'match($0, /[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+/) && !seen[substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)]++' file
```

Output

```
cat dog bear:tiger mouse elephant
cat dog bear:lion wolf frog
```

---

Or using `gnu awk`

```
awk 'match($0, /[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+/, a) && !seen[a[0]]++' file.txt
```

Comment: not clear what RSTART and RLENGTH should be here as this 2 word pattern can be anywhere in a single line. and also other words can have any number of lengths so its hard to predict exact lengths

Comment: @AlexB RSTART is the starting location of the match, and RLENGTH the length of the match. So you get the matched string using these values for `substr`, and you store that in `seen` See the [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function.

Comment: maybe also there is a way to add 2 patterns in this case. this is needed because words are separated. so for example WordC is a pattern and needs to be checked, then WordD ignored and WordE checked as second pattern

Comment: [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged. If you have a followup question then ask a new question, don't add requirements in comments (or significantly change your question) after getting answers.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the feedback, it is quite shorter now. Good point about the Chameleon questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
cat dog bear:tiger mouse elephant
cat dog bear:lion wolf frog
cat mouse bear:tiger frog wolf
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[[:alpha:]]*:[[:alpha:]]*"}!arr[$1]++{print $1}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
bear:tiger
bear:lion
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is zero-or-more (`*`) alphabetic characters followed by colon (`:`) followed by zero-or-more (`*`) alphabetic characters, thus in example there will be only one field which values are bear:tiger, bear:lion, bear:tiger then I use GNU `AWK` way of getting unique value, which for getting unique lines look as follows

```
awk '!arr[$0]++' file.txt
```

In this case we need to use 1st field value (`$1`) rather than whole line (`$0`) and `print` just that field not whole line (which is default action and thus applied when no action was explicitly given as in unique lines getter).

Disclaimer: this solution does always output first of duplicates.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!seen[$3]++' file
cat dog bear:tiger mouse elephant
cat dog bear:lion wolf frog
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input output, e.g. where the `Word:Word` string isn't always in the 3rd field and/or can occur multiple times on a line.